# Hosting Multiple Applications/Services on a Single VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vpn, vps, openvpn

I have recently purchased a RamNode OpenVZ VPS with the following specifications:

- 512MB RAM
- 512MB VSwap
- 2 CPU Cores @ 3.3GHz+
- 40GB SSD space
- 1Gbps Port
- 2000GB Bandwidth

At the moment, all I have installed on the VPS is OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net/). Additionally, I would like to use my VPS as a personal site, perhaps including a blog. Hence I was wondering if it is possible to also install and deploy a Ruby on Rails server on the VPS simultaneously.

In general, is it possible to deploy multiple applications/services on a single VPS, perhaps of different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally possible.  I have a Linode that runs a WordPress blog, a Rails app, a Sinatra app, hosts a private github repo using gitolite, and does a bunch of other stuff for me.

I've not used RamNode but they likely have documentation on setting stuff up like this.  Otherwise, you can find documentation on both SO and using Google for configuring webservers (like nginx) to work with different web application types.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was hoping to hear! Thank you :).